# Bash: Iterating over multiple arrays changes array values

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

If I iterate in bash over multiple arrays and printing its values then the values of the arrays changes. Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

a=("02" "20")
b=("02" "20")
n=("02" "20")
p=("02" "20")

for p in ${p[@]}
do
    for b in ${b[@]} 
    do
        for a in ${a[@]} 
        do 
           for n in ${n[@]} 
           do
             echo $b-$a-$n-$p
           done;
        done;
    done;
done
echo "${a[*]}"
```

The command `echo "${a[*]}"` yields `20 20` but should be `02 20`

Thanks!

Comment: You could have demonstrated this with a single array: `for a in ${a[@]}; do :; done`. In the future, please try to ***debug*** your problems yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
    for a in ${a[@]}
```

is reassigning the value of `a` (which in this case means reassigning the zeroth index of `a`).

Comment: Yup.    But it's only `${a[0]}` that is affected/changed since `a` is the same as `${a[0]}` if `a` is an array.